# OPL cannot extract expression error

Tags: cplex, opl

I try to create a set that dependent to a range in OPL (CPLEX)but I encounter 4 errors as follow:

1. Data element "a" not defined.
2. Invalid initialization expression for element "a".
3. OPL cannot extract expression: H[j].
4. OPL cannot extract model:  Out of Scope Index j out of scope in IntCollections[j].

I think that number 3 is major error.

initialization of code is as follow:

/*.mod*/

```
int n=...;                                  
int m=...;                                  
range I=1..m;                               
range J=1..n;                               
int h[J]=...;                                
int k[I]=...;                                
{int} H[j in J]={e|e in 1..h[j]};           
{int} K[i in I]={e|e in 1..k[i]};                   
int a[I][j in J][H[j]]=...;                 
int p[I][j in J][H[j]]=...;                  
int L=...;
```

/*.dat*/

```
n=2;
m=3;
h=[2 3];
k=[4 3 3];
a=[[[1 0][1 1 1]]
   [[1 1][0 0 1]]
   [[0 1][1 0 1]]];
L=1000;
p=[[[10 L][20 25 30]]
   [[15 12][L L 15]]
   [[L 18][25 L 25]]];
```

Thank you, that'll help me

Comment: Looks like you are defining `a[]` while `H[]` is not initialized. Did you try to write your data right in the .mod file without reading .dat file?

Comment: thank you for your attention an suggestion. I try that but does not work.

Comment: I guess you need to define `H[]` as set, not array.